# How to make ANTLR rule consume all possible elements, not only the first one?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

This is my grammar:

```
grammar test;
text: foo EOF;
foo: 'X' | foo tail;
tail: (' ' foo)+;
```

This is the input:

```
X X X X
```

The tree looks like this:

[image]

Instead, I expect only one `tail` to exist in the output tree, which must include three `foo` elements. How can I do that?

Comment: Each foo has to have its own tail, and so I would expect multiple tails would be seen.

Comment: Actually, `foo` doesn't need to have its own `tail`, according to the grammar

Comment: I don't see a `tail?` ending the `foo:` line

Comment: I believe `'X' | foo tail` means "either X or foo+tail`, isn't it?

Comment: Doesn't it mean 'X' or foo followed (always) by tail? Otherwise it should be `'X' | (foo tail);`

Comment: This way (with the brackets you suggested) it doesn't compile...

Comment: foo : 'X' tail; tail : (' ' 'X')*;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the left recursion from `foo: 'X' | foo tail;` you can better see why you get more than one `tail`:

```
foo: 'X' tail*;
```

This also works for multiple 'X' because `tail` contains another recursion (back to `foo`).

Comment: maybe you can help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634034/how-to-make-antlr-consume-all-visible-elements