# How to make ANTLR consume all visible elements?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

This is my grammar:

```
grammar test;
text: foo EOF;
foo:
    'X'
    |
    foo
    '!'
    |
    foo
    '?'
    |
    foo
    tail
    ;
tail: (' ' foo)+;
```

I'm parsing this text:

```
X? X! X X
```

This is the tree I'm getting:

[image]

What should change in the grammar so that I get only one `tail` element with a collection of all `foo` elements inside?

In the real world the task is way more complex, and using only a scanner is no solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you want is this:

```
item: 'X' ('!' | '?')*;
// Alternatively to get a tree per operator instead of a list of operators:
// item
//   : 'X'
//   | item '!'
//   | item '?'
//   ;
foo: item (' ' item)*;
```

Maybe this, if you want the tail still to have its own node in the tree:

```
item: 'X' ('!' | '?')*;
foo: item tail;
tail: (' ' item)*;
```

The reason that your version only gave you 1-item lists is that the mutual recursion between `foo` and `tail` consumed all the items, so there's nothing left for the repetition to consume.

Generally when you have something that can be repeated, you either want to implement this using `*`/`+` (if you want lists in the resulting tree) *or* using recursion (if you want a more tree-like tree) - not both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my real case it's a bit more complicated. It's hard to explain, but [here it is](https://github.com/yegor256/eo/blob/155/eo-compiler/src/main/antlr4/org/eolang/compiler/Program.g4#L99-L120). See the rules `hobject` and `htail`. Can you suggest what to do in this case?

Comment: @yegor256 That doesn't look substantially different to me. Just have an `item` rule (or whatever you want to call it) that contains everything for `hobject` except the part that calls `tail` and then define `hobject` as `item (SPACE item)*`.

Comment: The problem is that the definition of `hobject` includes other recursive rules, aside from the `htail` one. Thus, in my case the rule for `item` _must_ include the `item` recursively (like in my original sample). This means that I do need to combine recursion and repetition :(

Comment: @yegor256 But that's fine. Using recursion to allow another expression inside parenthesis is fine. You just shouldn't use recursion to allow multiple instances of `SPACE item` when you also use `+` to do the very same thing. The parentheses recursion will only match stuff in parentheses - it won't consume any instances of `SPACE item`, so it won't conflict with `(SPACE item)*`.

Comment: thanks for your help, please check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635366/how-to-make-antlr-consume-all-available-elements-using-recursion