# How to make ANTLR consume all available elements using recursion?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

This is my grammar:

```
grammar test;

text: foo EOF;

foo:
    'X'
    |
    '('
    foo
    ')'
    |
    foo
    '!'
    |
    foo
    tail
    ;

tail: (' ' foo)+;
```

This is the input it perfectly parses:

```
X (X! (X)! (X X X)!!!) X
```

However, the output tree has too many `tail` elements, as I explained earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634034/how-to-make-antlr-consume-all-visible-elements). Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Of course, but you will have to make an assumption where `tail` appears at. e.g., depth=1 from root: `foo: 'X' tail;
tail: (' ' foo2)+ ;
foo2: 'X' | '(' foo3 ')' | foo2 '!' ;
foo3: 'X' (' ' foo3)* | '(' foo3 ')' | foo3 '!' ;`. Alternatively, you could start with the original `foo` rule, add in the alt `| (' ' foo)+`, and add semantic predicates to choose `tail` only once. However, it's language-dependent, and likely requires a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Why's that a problem at all? With a listener you would not even see the deep nesting. Would be good to see your real problem you are trying to solve. Massaging the grammar to get a specific output is not going to work well, with a reasonably complex language.

Comment: @Mike In the listener I see too many instances of `tail`, which is wrong for my business case. For `X X X` input I need to see one `foo` and one `tail` instance, where the `tail` contains _two_ `foo`. Make sense?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `foo:  'X' tail? | '(' foo ')' tail? | foo '!' tail? ; tail: (' ' 'X' | ' ' '(' foo ')' | ' ' foo '!')+ ;` obtained via a redo of your grammar to make "tail" special, then several refactorings to remove the indirect left recursion. But, you'll likely reply that "it still has too many tail". This question has been asked three times, more or less. We just don't know what "too many tail" means. Draw out the tree of what you do want, then write a grammar from that, or write a tree to tree converter into the tree you need.

Comment: @kaby76 your recipe works just fine! Please, convert it to a full answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @yegor256 -- Glad it works. But let us leave it here. I very rarely ever post anything as an "answer" because I do not want people to modify my prose. Comments after 5 minutes cannot ever be modified, not by me! If any disagrees, just continue with the "comment" thread, and say I got it wrong. This is the one thing I do not like about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kaby76, the solution is found:

```
foo:  
  'X' tail? 
  | 
  '(' foo ')' tail? 
  | 
  foo '!' tail? 
  ; 
tail: 
  (
    ' ' 'X' 
    | 
    ' ' '(' foo ')' 
    | 
    ' ' foo '!'
  )+ 
  ;
```